# Adding markers to googlemap using xml

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm trying to add markers on googlemaps while  getting data using jQuery from XML file
but the marks don't show up

Function Called upon clicking on the radio button

```
 Route 1  <input type="radio" value="route1" name="1" onclick="addMarker();"/><br>
```

Adding Market Function

```
function addMarker() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "stationx.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
            $(data).find('station').each(function() {
                var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
                var lon = $(this).find('lon').text();
            });
        }
    });
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng("lat", "lon"),
        title: "Pittsburg/Bay Point"
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
}
```

This is the XML file "stationx.xml"

```
<stations>
<station>
<name>12th St. Oakland City Center</name>

<lat>37.803664</lat>
<lon>-122.271604</lon>

</station>
<station>
<name>16th St. Mission</name>

<lat>37.765062</lat>
<lon>-122.419694</lon>

</station>
</stations>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to move your logic for adding the marker into your loop of stations. And you should use your variables instead of just text strings `"lon"` vs `lon`

```
success: function(data) {
            $(data).find('station').each(function() {
                var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
                var lon = $(this).find('lon').text();
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
                  title: name
               });
               marker.setMap(map);
            });
        }
```